# Failed to link math library with intel mkl using g++

Tags: intel-mkl

I tried to compile with intel mkl 11.1 using g++:

```
g++ -m32 test.c -lmkl_intel -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm
```

The error says:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `logf'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `atan2'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `sin'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `fabs'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `exp'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `cos'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `log'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `pow'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `log10'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `ceil'
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/ia32/libmkl_core.so: undefined reference to `expf'
```

But, if I compile with

```
g++ -m32 test.c -lmkl_intel -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lm -liomp5 -lpthread -lm
```

There will be no error. I don't understand why added a -lm after the -lmkl_core will help, by the way

```
gcc -m32 test.c -lmkl_intel -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm
```

Turns out to be ok, I also don't understand what's the difference here.
Below is my test code.

```
/* C source code is found in dgemm_example.c */

#define min(x,y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mkl.h"

int main()
{
    double *A, *B, *C;
    int m, n, k, i, j;
    double alpha, beta;

    printf ("\n This example computes real matrix C=alpha*A*B+beta*C using \n"
            " Intel(R) MKL function dgemm, where A, B, and  C are matrices and \n"
            " alpha and beta are double precision scalars\n\n");

    m = 2000, k = 200, n = 1000;
    printf (" Initializing data for matrix multiplication C=A*B for matrix \n"
            " A(%ix%i) and matrix B(%ix%i)\n\n", m, k, k, n);
    alpha = 1.0; beta = 0.0;

    printf (" Allocating memory for matrices aligned on 64-byte boundary for better \n"
            " performance \n\n");
    A = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*k*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    B = (double *)mkl_malloc( k*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    C = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    if (A == NULL || B == NULL || C == NULL) {
        printf( "\n ERROR: Can't allocate memory for matrices. Aborting... \n\n");
        mkl_free(A);
        mkl_free(B);
        mkl_free(C);
        return 1;
    }

    printf (" Intializing matrix data \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (m*k); i++) {
        A[i] = (double)(i+1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (k*n); i++) {
        B[i] = (double)(-i-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (m*n); i++) {
        C[i] = 0.0;
    }

    printf (" Computing matrix product using Intel(R) MKL dgemm function via CBLAS interface \n\n");
    cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 
            m, n, k, alpha, A, k, B, n, beta, C, n);
    printf ("\n Computations completed.\n\n");

    printf (" Top left corner of matrix A: \n");
    for (i=0; i<min(m,6); i++) {
        for (j=0; j<min(k,6); j++) {
            printf ("%12.0f", A[j+i*k]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    printf ("\n Top left corner of matrix B: \n");
    for (i=0; i<min(k,6); i++) {
        for (j=0; j<min(n,6); j++) {
            printf ("%12.0f", B[j+i*n]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    printf ("\n Top left corner of matrix C: \n");
    for (i=0; i<min(m,6); i++) {
        for (j=0; j<min(n,6); j++) {
            printf ("%12.5G", C[j+i*n]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    printf ("\n Deallocating memory \n\n");
    mkl_free(A);
    mkl_free(B);
    mkl_free(C);

    printf (" Example completed. \n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, placing -lm two times allowed me to build MAGMA with MKL.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Any updates on this? Having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on Debian and I follow the steps below to successfully run and compile one of the example programs in mkl:

- I use [script.sh](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb) to automatically install the necessary packages (need to use `sudo`)
- Run one of example programs ([this one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-tutorial-c-multiplying-matrices-using-dgemm#9CEED00C-1A85-4AC0-8AF8-BE2AFEF0E603) for example) as following:
  ([ref](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/c_bindings.htm))

  1. `$ export MKLROOT=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mkl`
  2. `$ cc -fopenmp -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include test.c -Wl,--no-as-needed -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_gnu_thread -lpthread -lm -ldl`
  3. `$ ./a.out`